# RegEx for C++ class parser

Tags: c++, regex, class, pattern-recognition

I am creating a C++ class parser and I am trying to get the info from the header and the source file of a class.

I would like to get all the info about the class, specifically from the header first I need:

- the headers to be included
- other declarations and defines
- the class name, the class access specifiers and the base classes names and access specifiers
- the class constructors and destructor
- the class members and their info
- the class methods and their info
- other nested struct or classes

For now I was kind of able to get the headers and the class name.
I got stuck at the class members as they can have several modifiers, the return type, can be written as Class::method or just method and finally they have constrains on their naming.

As an example I have tried the following regex

```
^(\s*(?:(?:virtual|inline|constexpr|static|friend|override)\s+)?((?!Automobile)[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\s*)((Automobile::(?!Automobile)[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)|((?!Automobile)[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?!::)))).+
```

just for the part of the method up to the brackets. The problem is that it recognizes

```
Automobile::Automobile() {
Automobile::Automobile(int a, int b) {
Automobile::Automobile();
Automobile::Automobile(int a, int b);
Automobile::Automobile(int a, int b)
Automobile::Automobile()
void Automobile::start   //-> this
bool Automobile::start()    //-> this
Automobile() 
constexpr void Automobile::start  \n    //-> this
Autamobile::start //-> this 
inline corri()//-> this
void Automobile::1_cjoin() //-> this 
run()//-> this
```

Of course the last four ones should not be matched.

Is there any good soul who would help me correcting the regex for this or (if willing) helping me with my project? In case I will give the link to the repo.

Thanks!

Comment: Regular expressions are powerful, but they can't really be used to parse C++. Or any language which have nested structures. Regular expressions traditionally can't handle nested structure, and even with modern extensions it's still not generally possible. When it is, it tends to create regular expressions that are more or less write-only and unmaintainable. Use regular expression for the *lexer* to recognize tokens, but use some other way to parse the tokens.

Comment: What you really want to perhaps make use of would be a [BNF Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) of C++ for parsing purposes. Even if you went with regex, an approach that uses _multiple_ regexes to notice sub-patterns instead of a single monolithic regex would be ideal.

Comment: What about using an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) tool for C++? I don't know one for C/C++, but I'm pretty sure you'll find one given with gcc or clang. Or perhaps even an online tool similar to [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I will try what @Rogue suggested. I would like to do everything from scratch as it is part of my personal project. If not I will look for tools. Still I leave the question open for now to check if someone has a suggestion on the specific case.